# Latex listings package, issue with caption touching the frame and junk character instead of space

Tags: formatting, listings, captions

I am using `listings` package and facing two issues

Following is the LaTeX code and output

```
\lstset{language=Java, basicstyle=\small, frame=single, breaklines=true, postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookrightarrow\space}}}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Utils.java},label={lst:JOOQ-LGRN}] 
CATCH CLAUSE : catch (Exception fatal) {
  log.error("Cannot parse Postgres array: " + rs.getString(index));
  log.error(fatal);
  return null;
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image: Issues are marked in red color]

1. There is a junk character which is appearing instead of a space. I have marked it in red. For example between "Cannot" and "parse", between "parse" and "Postgres".
2. The caption is touching the line/frame – how do I create some space between the caption and line/frame

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

The “explicit space” symbols are due to the setting `showstringspaces=true` that's the default with `lstlisting`.

The `IEEEtran` class knows just two types of captions, those for tables and those for figures. If an environment is not `table`, the class assumes the caption is for a figure, so it adjusts the spacing for it being placed below the picture. My suggestion is to use the format for table captions, for uniformity.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\lstset{
  language=Java, 
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible, 
  frame=single, 
  breaklines=true, 
  postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookrightarrow\space}},
  showstringspaces=false,% no symbol for spaces in strings
}

% Persuade IEEEtran into believing a listing is a table
\makeatletter
\preto\lstlisting{\def\@captype{table}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Utils.java},label={lst:JOOQ-LGRN}] 
CATCH CLAUSE : catch (Exception fatal) {
  log.error("Cannot parse Postgres array: " + rs.getString(index));
  log.error(fatal);
  return null;
  a test with a single quote 'Cannot parse Postgres array:';
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I added `\ttfamily` to `basicstyle` and `columns=fullflexible` because I can't stand listings in the normal text font with letters spaced in uneven fashion.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. This is because the Java language in `listings` has

   ```
   morestring=[b]",%
   ```

   (this can be found in the file `lstlang1.sty`) to avoid this, you can use `deletestring`, as in:

   ```
   deletestring=[b]",
   ```

   Since the language also sets

   ```
   morestring=[b]',%
   ```

   you might also be interested in

   ```
   deletestring=[b]',%
   ```

   to avoid the same phenomenon with single quotes.
2. I cannot reproduce this in my example below; the position of the caption in your image suggests that you qre not using one of the standard classes, so please edit your question adding a simple, yet *complete* document (like the one in my answer below) allowing us to reproduce the problem with the caption.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  language=Java, 
  basicstyle=\small, 
  frame=single, 
  breaklines=true, 
  postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookrightarrow\space}},
  deletestring=[b]",
  deletestring=[b]'
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Utils.java},label={lst:JOOQ-LGRN}] 
CATCH CLAUSE : catch (Exception fatal) {
  log.error("Cannot parse Postgres array: " + rs.getString(index));
  log.error(fatal);
  return null;
  a test with a single quote 'Cannot parse Postgres array:';
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the perfect answer – I really appreciate it. Issue (1) is resolved. Issue (2) – you are right that by changing the document class to “article”, the problem is fixed. 
However, I am using a standard document class: \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}. The class is downloaded from IEEE website (used by authors of hundreds of IEEE conferences)
http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html
I am using: A4 (DOC, 56 KB) Windows (ZIP, 700 KB). I have to use IEEEtran as I am submitting a paper to an IEEE conference and cannot use \documentclass{article}